# How do upload an Image to django from angularjs client using django rest framework?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I can't figure out how I should post an Image from angularjs.
I'm a newbie in django and django-rest-framework.
Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='UserImages')
   user=models.ForeignKey(Profile)

   # highlighted = models.TextField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
   likes=JSONField(null=True,blank=True)
   image=models.ImageField()
   pub_date=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.owner)
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('gett_image_url')
class Meta:
    model=UserImages
    fields=('id','owner','image','likes','image','image_url','owner')
def gett_image_url(self,obj):
    return obj.image.url
```

views.py(what I've tried)

```
class Profile_List(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
def get(self, request, format=None):
    profiles=Profile.objects.all()
    serializer=ProfileSerializer(profiles, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
def post(self, request, format=None):
    req=request.data
    image = req['display_image']
    req['user']=self.request.user.id
    #self.request.user.
    serializer=ProfileSerializer(data=req)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

I can't figure out how i should design the view, I read something about FileUploadParser but its going way over my head a code snippet of the view would be nice.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what all you have tried in View. Assuming you are using a newer version of Django RF then request.data['image'] should directly give you the InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: @KetanJogani I have added the view.
Should I do do anything else to make sure the image is saved?

Comment: are you providing the filename in url or passing it via the content deposition header.  If you are not sure how to use FileUploadParser, rather normally receive the file from request.data and save it.